# Escape characters in Google AppEngine full text search

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using full text search and I'd like to search for items that have a property with value 'C+'

is there a way I can escape the '+' Char so that this search would work?

Comment: could you add some input/output or code ?

Comment: @kmad1729, What are you looking for?  Are asking him to provide this?: `index.search("C+")`

Comment: The exact search is Index.search("stage:%s" % stage) # Stage = 'C+'

Answer (score 0):

It might help to include the code in question, but try putting a `\` before the `+`, that's what can escape things within quotes in python, so it might work here. E.g.: `C\+`